# tensorflow tutorial mnist_with_summary throws TypeError

Tags: tensorflow, typeerror, tensorboard

I am running the mnist_with_summary tutorial to see how the TensorBoard works. It throws a TypeError right away.

```
Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bruceho/workspace/TestTensorflow/mysrc/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 166, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/Users/bruceho/workspace/TestTensorflow/mysrc/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 163, in main
    train()
  File "/Users/bruceho/workspace/TestTensorflow/mysrc/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 110, in train
    y = nn_layer(dropped, 500, 10, 'layer2', act=tf.nn.softmax)
  File "/Users/bruceho/workspace/TestTensorflow/mysrc/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 104, in nn_layer
    activations = act(preactivate, 'activation')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 582, in softmax
    return _softmax(logits, gen_nn_ops._softmax, dim, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 542, in _softmax
    logits = _swap_axis(logits, dim, math_ops.sub(input_rank, 1))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 518, in _swap_axis
    0, [math_ops.range(dim_index), [last_index],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 991, in range
    return gen_math_ops._range(start, limit, delta, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1675, in _range
    delta=delta, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 490, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 657, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 180, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 163, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 353, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 290, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32, got 'activation' of type 'str' instead.
```

I tried running from inside eclipse and command line with the same results. Any one experience the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have modified the original code somehow. Your problem lies in this line:`activations = act(preactivate, 'activation')`. So if you check the api of [tf.nn.softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax), you would find that the second argument represents `dim` instead of `name`. So to fix the problem, just change this line into:`activations = act(preactivate, name='activation')`

Besides, I don't know if you have changed

`diff = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_)`

If not, you probably have `softmax` the output twice.

Comment: Hey, that fixed it. So it looks like Tensorflow team checked in buggy code. Is that uncharacteristic?

Comment: There is some precedent for that :). But I had to go [back to the `r0.10` branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py#L103) to find that line of code with `'activation'` as an non-keyword argument. Is it possible you're running that code with a newer installation? There have been breaking changes between the minor releases, and so it's important to run the example code from the same release as your installed TensorFlow package.

Comment: Yes, I am running the latest tensorflow r0.12. I think it's safer and more clear to explicitly tell 'activation' is assigned to `name` by passing in `name='activation'`